# Bitmap image file to int

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have some problem with my code..
I want to set value luckywheelitem library from https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel ,

I have image file from gallery then convert to bitmap

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Luckywheel";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root+ "/sarada.png" );
```

Then i want set value `luckyItem1.icon = ;` but just receive **integer** value

how to convert from image bitmap to int (drawable)
[image]

Thank you for attention

Comment: maybe you need do some tweak with your library.

Comment: Resources and their IDs are constructed at build time. You cannot make a dynamically-created `Bitmap` into a resource, nor can you link it to a resource ID. Looking at the source, you cannot do what your attempting with that library. Honestly, it's not that great, to begin with; e.g., its drawing routine is horribly inefficient. Perhaps you can find another that will do what you want.

Comment: hello @DennyKurniawan Indonesia :D

Comment: ok thanks for the advice @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to `luckyItem1.icon` only a resource file. You should add drawable to your project and then use it.

Example:

```
luckyItem1.icon = R.drawable.luckyItemIcon
```

Comment: but my image from server hmm

Comment: @senaa unfortunately this library does not provide this feature

Comment: @senaa if this answer help you, please select it as correct answer